# Adsense Ads not showing up in I.E. (internet explorer)

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, adsense

Any of you Internet Explorer experts out there have any ideas why my adsense ads do not show up specifically in I.E. for this domain: http://www.diablo3values.com/  The ads work fine if Chrome and Firefox.  I have tried several different things such as removing the wrapping divs/elements as well as simply putting the ad in the body element were it is not manipulated by backbone, but still nothing.  What is strange however is that the ads do work on a different page on the same site (http://www.diablo3values.com/attributes).  I am guessing this is because this page does not use backbone. Any ideas?

I have been testing in I.E. 9 and am using backbone.js, jquery mobile, and google app engine.

Comment: side note: I find it interesting that of the **70 HTTP network requests** for that page in IE **only 1** is actually from your domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the IE console: " Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: Well, Dont know what happened but, they are working now... I didn't change anything